# Connecting all the computers to a database which is running in another desktop

Tags: mysql, database-connection, application-server

I am not much familiar about this but have some queries.
I have installed MySQL database in a desktop and using it for creating a web application in my workplace. After the app gets created, I want all the computers to have an access to the database in the desktop I have used as it has all the DB tables.

One more thing I want to know that as the application needs application server to run it, is there any way I can achieve it in this scenario.

Thanks.

Comment: If you created web application then why you need to connect database from different machine ?
you can host application in any machine and use via intranet instead of.

Comment: you mean by configuring the ip of the machine (where the applicaion is residing) in other connecting machines?